# Only some CSS loads on mobile, work perfect on Desktop

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

The website works and looks perfect on desktop, even while scaling the browser everything work. When I load it on mobile it looks totally off, only SOME of the css loads, to make it even weirder, it work sometimes and sometimes it does not. I checked  all the tags on the head section for the responsive code to work, and its all correct. I have no idea what could be wrong. Here's the link to the website http://flits.live/ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have many instances of Media query specific CSS here.

Let's take your class `.phone-screen` for example,

```
    @media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px)
    .phone_screen {
        width: 240px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(80px);
        transform: translateY(80px);
    }
```

The width element here specifies that *only* when the window is within the 768px- 991px range then a width of 240px will be applied to the `phone-screen` class.

The only CSS that would technically not be loaded and implemented to the output would be within media queries that are false. This code will not be 'loaded' if the window width is less than 768px (Bootstrap's standard "xs" breakpoint) or more than 991px (Bootstrap's standard "md" breakpoint).

(More on Bootstrap's breakpoints: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

The structure is poor on the site and I would strongly suggest actually implementing bootstrap, found at http://getbootstrap.com/ this will really help you in understanding how things need to be structured for responsiveness. You can't just throw divs next to each other and assume things won't start disappearing in smaller windows (actually, going 'off-screen' in your case due to the media queries as mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

For mobile max width is 767 not 768 ok so consider this thing.
You written media query for ipad not for mobile ok.
so written like this.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px)
    .phone_screen {
        width: 240px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(80px);
        transform: translateY(80px);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement bootstrap.   I've cleaned up the HTML for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/w8crtf2p/

Once you've cleaned up the code yourself add the following code to your `head` tag.  You can remove the optional theme if you want.

Then look through [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) and see what you need on your website.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```